# I have an idea which would produce a minuscule delta-v without expending mass. Would it work? Why or why not?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, forces, kinematics

The idea is that an electromagnetic cannon shoots a rubber ball that contains a core of ferromagnetic matter into a box. The box closes and the ball will bounce back and forth with increasingly lower kinetic energy while the box has an overall increase in speed. The net delta-V as time -> infinity would be slightly less than the force the ball was shot with divided by the mass of the box. The air cannon is attached to the box and the box is closed by a mechanism that's perfectly balanced as to not induce angular momentum. Based on the very easy calculations that I did, if the whole apparatus minus the ball being shot weighs 1 kilogram and the ball itself weighs 0.1 kilograms, the apparatus would travel backwards from where the cannon is aiming and the ball would be travelling in the reverse direction, eventually entering the box and getting trapped inside. As the ball's surface is made of rubber, it'll bounce, effectively distributing some of it's kinetic energy to the box slowing it down with a fraction of the energy used to create the backwards motion. Since the ball weighs less than the apparatus, the impact will send it with more speed in the opposite direction. The two speeds will get closer and closer every second collision, but the velocity will be different than what is was before the firing of the cannon.

Answer (score 2):

No, this wouldn't work. The net momentum of the whole system is zero, so the motion of the center of mass of the system is zero. The apparatus as a whole would move forward a small, finite amount (roughly $\frac{1}{10}$ of its length with the numbers you gave) that balances out the motion of the ball moving backwards.

The overall system didn't lose any mass, but the propulsion part did: if you moved the ball back to the cannon without expending any mass, the rest of the apparatus would shift back to where it started.